# Number Masked Textbox value can't be stored to Money Datatype Table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik

Hi I'm just starting to learn about C# on VS 2 days ago..so I'm really new on this, please pardon if this question is noob.

I'm trying to create a purchase form that will stored the data input to my db, and I already make the table same as the form.

so here's the code :

```
private void ConfirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.DateTime myDate = default(System.DateTime);
        myDate = DateInput.Value;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;integrated security=SSPI");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO transaction_record values(@DATE,@OP,@NAME,@USERID,@GAME,@BANK,@AMOUNT)", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OpInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MemberInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MemberIdInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GameInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BANK", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BankInput.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Decimal.Parse(AmountInput.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

and my AmountInput.text is using telerik masked textbox with number masking.
When i try to store the value to my db.transaction_record @amount column that has money datatype, it return error "cannot convert 'int' to 'System.Globalization.NumberStyles'

Please help me..

Comment: Which line gives the error? What value you are getting in `AmountInput.Text`?

Comment: this line "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Decimal.Parse(AmountInput.Text);" gives error "cannot convert 'int' to 'System.Globalization.NumberStyles'

Comment: AmountInput.Text is decimal number but using telerik masked textbox I make it display value XXX.XXX, how can I store it to table with money datatype

Comment: This error comes when you pass second argument to Decimal.Parse as integer while it expects NumberStyles as second parameter. Are you sure you are sharing the same code which has the error? Are you getting error at compile time or runtime?

Comment: what kind of format is `XXX.XXX`? What if you enter 23.02 in textbox, what is  `AmountInput.Text` value? Is it 23.02_ or X23.02 or 23.02X...?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya sorry wrong error..with "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Decimal.Parse(AmountInput.Text);" i'm getting System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value" i don't quite understand, why the problem shifted to my datetime parameters..

Comment: I mean if i put 100000 the display value will be 100.000 on runtime, but when i press the btn it wont store to table..if can i want it to display 100.000 in the table as well.. @Nino

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya before the error show up when run time when i input the  number value in text box and press confirm, but now the error show up on compile time